# .hover() function . Resetting animation

Tags: jquery, animation, hover, jquery-animate

My problem is that I'm using the jquery function '.hover()', it works fine, if I move the mouse over the divs slowly. When I turn things up and start to move around the mouse pointer very fastly, the animations won't stop and even worse! Everything starts to moving around the page without resetting to its initial position.

The bit of code:

```
$('.popProdContainer').hover(function(e){
             $(this).find('.pdtprice').stop().animate({"left": "-=70px"}, "slow");
             $(this).find('.pdtcartBkt, .pdtcartAdd').show('slow');
         },function(e){
             $(this).find('.pdtprice').stop().animate({"left": "+=70px"}, "slow");
             $(this).find('.pdtcartBkt, .pdtcartAdd').hide('slow');
});
```

So, this is what I have. Tried to put behind the .animate this:

```
.filter(':not(:animated)')
```

Didn't work.

Comment: Did you try using `.stop(true, true)`? But maybe you should check out the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include the solution... it leads to confusion and the question remains "open".  I rolled it back.  Please post your solution below as an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: hoverIntent, didn't work either.

Comment: You're right. Done that.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

I hope this turns helpful to others:

```
$('.popProdContainer').bind('mouseenter',function(){
    $('.pdtprice', this).animate({
        marginLeft: "-0.6in"
    },500);

    $('.pdtcartBkt', this).fadeIn('fast');
    $('.pdtcartAdd', this).fadeIn('fast');
}).bind('mouseleave',function(){
    $('.pdtprice', this).animate({
        marginLeft: "0.6in"
    },500);

    $('.pdtcartBkt', this).fadeOut('fast');
    $('.pdtcartAdd', this).fadeOut('fast');
});
```